# Polynomial's coefficients calculation for inequality terms

Tags: functions, inequality, polynomials

I've a problem with calculation procedure for parameters of a polynomial. Let we say, that we've defined range $[x_{a}, x_{b}]$ in which values of function $ f(x)$ is less that $y_{max}$. As a $f(x)$ function I treat any polynomial or rational function constructed from parameters $a, b, c, d$ e.g. $f(x)=a \cdot x^4+b \cdot x^2 - \frac{1}{c} \cdot x+d$. Now, I want to calculate such parameters (a, b, c, d) for which mentioned assumption is met - $f(x) < y_{max}$ for $[x_{a}, x_{b}]$. Could you please tell me, how can I resolve such problem ?

Regards,
E.

Comment: Is the derivative from calculus a tool with which you are familiar?

Comment: Let's say I know what a derivative is, but I've never used it. Can you explain how it can be used here?

Comment: What is $y_{max}$? if this is the max. value of the function, then any set of values for the coefficients will do. No need to calculate anything. I suggest you give an example.

Comment: Ok, so I'll try to be much more precise. In mentioned range $[x_{a}, x_{b}]$ the values of a function must be less than $y_{max}$, and outside this range, values must be greater than $y_{max}$. This question born after my reflecions about polynomials, and usage of them. I just want to synthesize such function, which can met such assumtions. If you want to have some example hmmm... let we say, that in [0, 2pi] $f(x) < -1$, and in other cases: $f(x) >= -1$. A considered polynomial: $f(x)=a \cdot x^4 + b \cdot x^3 + c \cdot x^2 + d$

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then the interval would be $[0.742, 3.334]$ and $y_{max}=1$ in this link:https://www.desmos.com/calculator/emutnr0vnr In this case, ${y_max} is just an upper limit not the local maximum.

Comment: Nope- I want to have fixed interval from 0 up to 2π, and $y_{max}=-1$ . Those are FIXED design values. I want to calculate a, b, c, d polynomial parameters for such assumptions,,,-how can i do that?

Comment: Any other suggestions ?